# Typedef redefinition with different types nsuinteger (aka unsigned int) vs cdvdestinationtype

Tags: c++, typedef, redefinition

I am using Cordova, `#import <Cordova/CDV.h>` and in my project, I use another library which is in C++ style, so, my file has to be `*.mm`.

The problem is that when I compile, I get the following error:

```
typedef redefinition with different types nsuinteger (aka unsigned int) vs cdvdestinationtype
```

This error is in `CDVCamera.h`:

```
enum CDVDestinationType {
    DestinationTypeDataUrl = 0,
    DestinationTypeFileUri
};
typedef NSUInteger CDVDestinationType;
```

It seems that the problem comes from the fact that I mix Objective-C and C++.

How can I solve it?

Comment: when one says 'typedef NSUInteger CDVDestinationType;' means CDVDestinationType is typedef for NSUInteger but CDVDestinationType is enum, one can't redefine type.